# Can HashiCorp Vault give out rolling passwords and keep a copy so a human can get a particular password

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I have several systems labeled A-Z. My question is can Vault generate a password upon request from each of my systems A-Z and allow a user to see only the password for a particular system like system R? A human needs to be able to login to the Vault and search for that systems password so they can enter it and begin work.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to both create the proper ACL policies and automate the generation, storage, retrieval of those passwords. Vault does have an endpoint for generating random bytes (https://www.vaultproject.io/api/system/tools.html#generate-random-bytes).

Also note that Vault doesn't support any kind of versioning of secrets currently. Workaround would be to store each password at a different path so you can keep the history if needed (secret/hostname/ password=thingy). I haven't seen any tools out there that do any of this for you but its also not too complicated of a use case.